# How to make each Div is a section that occupies the entire height of Body?

Tags: css, html, web

How to implement the following:

I want a div spans the width and height of the body, and when you scroll down you see another Div occupy the same width and height of the body, as shown in the following page

https://www.lexcorp.io/#/home

How is this possible?

Comment: inheriting height from viewport: html,body, body>* {height:100%;} no secret just cascade ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use viewport units.

> Viewport-percentage lengths defined a length relatively to the size of viewport, that is the visible portion of the document. Only Gecko-based browsers are updating the viewport values dynamically, when the size of the viewport is modified (by modifying the size of the window on a desktop computer or by turning the device on a phone or a tablet).

```
div {
height:100vh; 
max-height:100vh;
}
```

[**CanIUse.com - Viewport Units**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units)

Comment: The height looks good, but when scroll down are both Div, and you should see only one at a time

Comment: Not sure what you are saying. That's expected behaviour. Anything else would require javascript.

Comment: Ok, thanks for CSS It has been very useful for me

Comment: To have the functionality you described @PaulieD is correct it will require javascript/jQuery. There is a great open source plugin that does exactly what your describe if you don't want to build the functionality yourself. Its called FullPage.js - http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/

Answer (score 1):

sorry my initial code was crap. I noticed that original website didn't even use a scrollbar. here's a modified version that uses transforms and mousewheel for extra smoothness.

https://jsfiddle.net/foreyez/f48j27f0/

```
var pageSize = $(window).height();
$( window ).resize(function() {
   pageSize = $(window).height();
});
$('div').bind('mousewheel', function(e) {
    if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta / 120 > 0) 
    {
    //up
     $('#container').css('transform','translateY(0px)');
    } else {
    //down
        $('#container').css('transform','translateY(-' + pageSize + 'px)');
    }
});
```

Comment: It is exactly what I wanted, thanks

Comment: @Berroterán here you go

Answer (score 0):

If browser support is an issue, you can also do:

```
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```